# How is "watch strap pin" called in French?

Tags: terminologie

I really can't find in any dictionary how the thing below is called in French; it's the *watch strap pin* in English (called an *axis* in some other languages, it's the thing that attaches the strap to the wrist watches).

[image: a watch strap pin]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is called [barette or pompe](http://www.venus-diffusion.com/la-boutique/barrettes-ou-pompes/).

Answer (score 2):

A *watch strap pin* is called [*une barrette*](http://www.watchstyle.fr/pd1681676152.htm?defaultVariants=search0_EQ_20%20mm_AND_%7BEOL%7D&categoryId=157) in French.

Answer (score 2):

The term used by watchmakers is 'pompe'.